# Can you run games that require a Memory Card on a PS Vita Slim or PS Vita TV without it?

Tags: ps-vita, ps-vita-tv

Some games like Project Diva f/f 2nd require a Memory Card to be inserted in the console for the game to work. Is possible to run this type of games without a Memory Card in the 2nd Generation PS Vita (Slim) or the PS Vita TV? (as both consoles should have 1GB of internal memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, as long as it fits on the 1GB of internal memory.

For example, f and f 2nd needs internal storage for Saved Data and Edit Data, both which are not over a couple of megabytes in size.